# A Fourier inversion problem

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let's say I have a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{Z})\cap L^2(\mathbb{Z}).$ Now using Plancherel I can get a function $g\in L^2(S^1)$ such that $\hat{g}=f$. Now I want to say $g\in L^1(S^1)$ so that I can apply Fourier inversion. Is there a way to show that or it's not always true?

Comment: Since $S^1$ is compact, it's a finite measure space. And in case of finite measure spaces $L^p \subset L^1, \forall p$ trivially!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since $S^1$ is a bounded set, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives you
$$
∫_{S^1} |g| ≤ |S^1|^{1/2}  \,\|g\|_{L^2(S^1)}.
$$

Comment: $\hat{g}=f$ is a function on $\mathbb{Z}$, how are you integrating it on $S^1$?

Comment: Oh sorry I meant $g$. Corrected. It is what you are looking for right?

Comment: Oh, I see; I should have seen the finite measure fact.